Shell script: Bad Substitution for argument indices
Usually I find solutions for more complex tasks in shell scripts by breaking down longer commands into a sequence of simple commands. Here is one where I couldn't find a solution with this method.
I need to do calculations, in order to know which argument I need to use. Once I have it, I can call it, like here (simplified, generic version):
    1 i=1
    2 k=$(( i+1 ))
    3 echo $i
    4 echo $k
    5 echo "${!i}"
    6 echo "${!k}"

As to be expected:
    $ ./testo A B 
    1
    2
    A
    B

Firstly, I found that expression with an exclamation mark somewhere in the Interwebs, and I was happy to have it, because it works. I don't understand what it does, however.
In my opinion, ! usually means not, but here it exactly works. Without, however, it doesn't. I'd like to learn, why.
Now I wanted to simplify the code, and remove the - I think - unnecessary second line by substituting the k in the last line with an arithmetic expression, as in line 2.
To my surprise, neither of my efforts of copying the expression for k from the second line actually works:
    1 i=1
    2 k=$(( i+1 ))
    3 echo $i
    4 echo $k
    5 echo "${!i}"
    6 echo "${!k}"
    7 echo "${!$(( i+1 ))}"
    8 echo "${!(( i+1 ))}"
    9 echo "${!(( $i+1 ))}"

, as can be seen here:
    ./testo: line 7: ${!$(( i+1 ))}: bad substitution
    ./testo: line 8: ${!(( i+1 ))}: bad substitution
    ./testo: line 9: ${!(( $i+1 ))}: bad substitution

What do I do wrong; what would be a good substition; why can't I just copy the expression for k of line 2 into the place of k in line 6?

Have a read through Shell Parameter Expansion. About half-way down the page it gets into ${!prefix*}.

I had actually seen that, read up and down, but couldn't understand. How is the i or k equatable with prefix* or so? There are numbers of examples in that document, but nothing to this topic.
Thanks anyway

Besides my answer below, I also edited your tags. I removed [tag:shell] and added [tag:bash], as this only applies to bash shell. If you are working in any other shell, my answer below is incorrect and you will need to specify (by correct tag) which shell you are targeting.

Expansions are not macros. To expand you have to have a variable. You can't optimize it. It's fine, presented code is perfect.

I don't understand what it doe

Indirect expansion is documented in bash manual. See What is indirect expansion? What does ${!var*} mean? and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html .

and remove the - I think - unnecessary second line by substituting the k in the last line with an arithmetic expression, as in line 2

No possible.

What do I do wrong

Nothing.

what would be a good substition

k=$(( i+1 )); echo "${!k}" is perfect substitution

why can't I just copy the expression for k of line 2 into the place of k in line 6?

Expansions are not macros. The ${! has to expand a variable. You can't chain expansions, they are just not parsed or implemented that way.

From official documentation (paragraph 4):

If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), and parameter is not a nameref, it introduces a level of indirection. Bash uses the value formed by expanding the rest of parameter as the new parameter; this is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the expansion, rather than the expansion of the original parameter. This is known as indirect expansion.

So in your example "${!i}", where i has the value of 1, after indirect expansion becomes "$1". $1 is the first argument passed to your example script, A in your case. That is what the echo outputs.
Your other examples "${!$(( i+1 ))}" and "${!(( i+1 ))}", using indirect expansion, become nonsense. $(( i+1 )) and (( i+1 )) are both invalid parameter names, and so you get bad substitution error. Note that "stuff" after the ! is not again evaluated, it is treated as a parameter name literally.
